# How to convert terminal window chat application (built using socket programming, written in python) into a web application?

Tags: python, sockets, web-applications, chat

*So, I wrote this chat application which works well in terminal windows:
[GitHub Source](https://github.com/sahildua2305/py-socketchat)*

Now what I want is to **convert into a web chat application** so that my friends can connect/chat/test it from their network. But, I am clueless about how to proceed!

Please help me. Suggest me which technologies can I use to make it available on a website?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've written a Python server to handle your Python chat clients, and you'd like to extend this to web clients.

I would recommend using a **real-time network** such as PubNub to relay data between your chat clients and the server. Using a real-time network means that you can spend less time worrying about low-level socket issues such as concurrency and more time building your application.

In the case of PubNub, a [Python SDK](https://github.com/pubnub/python) will allow your server to subscribe to chat channels, while the [JavaScript SDK](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/javascript-sdk.html) will help with web-based clients. You can build a simple JavaScript-based web client using the code in this blog post: [Build Real-Time Chat Apps in 10 Lines of Code](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-real-time-chat-10-lines-code/).

```
Enter Chat and press enter
<div><input id=input placeholder=you-chat-here /></div>

Chat Output
<div id=box></div>

<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js></script>
<script>(function(){
  var box = PUBNUB.$('box'), input = PUBNUB.$('input'), channel = 'chat';
  PUBNUB.subscribe({
    channel : channel,
    callback : function(text) { box.innerHTML = (''+text).replace( /[<>]/g, '' ) + '<br>' + box.innerHTML }
  });
  PUBNUB.bind( 'keyup', input, function(e) {
    (e.keyCode || e.charCode) === 13 && PUBNUB.publish({
      channel : channel, message : input.value, x : (input.value='')
    })
  } )
})()</script>
```

Then, on your Python server, you could subscribe to the same chat channel:

```
# Listen for Messages *BLOCKING*
def receive(message) :
  broadcast_data(message) #This is using your Python function from your github link
  return True

pubnub.subscribe({
  'channel'  : 'chat',
  'callback' : receive 
})
```

Let me know if this works for you. Good luck!

Comment: And if you are super-adventurous, email support@pubnub.com for advance-access to our new 3.5 beta PubNub Python client !